# how do you make an image, a var, and a string all on the same line with no line breaks?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to change the innerHTML of a p to an image and a var with NO line breaks. When I try the code I thought should work, it breaks my code. when I view sorce, it says syntax error in the code right where I try to put the image.

I've tried, document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML =  + gold;  this breaks my code in a few different spots, like buttons showing up blank.

```
    <p id="demo"><img src="Game_Images/gold.png"></p>
<script>
var gold = 0;
//display gold image and gold var on same line
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = <img 
src="Game_Images/gold.png"> + gold;
</script>
```

Expected results: Image and var on same line.
Actual results: Broken code and blank buttons.
error messages in editor: Syntax error, (exactly where I try to insert the image on innerHTML change).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that you haven't made that first img tag a string. You will also have to use escape sequences for the src attribute.

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<img src=\"Game_Images/gold.png\">" + gold;
```

When you use the innerHTML property of an element, it expects a properly formed html string, so make sure you are always assigning a string to innerHTML, and not just plain markup.

[MDN Article on innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

Comment: Schroeder I don't understand why the first forward slash you used to use "escape sequences" for the src attribute is on the outside of the quotation, and the second is on the inside of the quotes, but the code works and I can't argue with results.

Comment: @JohnThompson The escape sequence character \ is used to escape the double quotes in your src attribute. It ensures that we don't break the string up. The outer "" that enclose the img tag are delimiting the string. Also, if this answer worked for you, mark it as correct please!

Comment: My bad on not marking it correct right away. The code you provided works like a charm. I'm still new to this site, and I'm still learning the rules.

Comment: @JohnThompson no worries, we were all new once! Read up on how strings and escape sequences work and you should be all set for stuff like this.